# ARM Deliberately Bloating Compiled Code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, compiler-optimization

While working on the issue in [Fastest Cortex M0+ Thumb 32x32=64 multiplication function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286239/fastest-cortex-m0-thumb-32x32-64-multiplication-function) I wrote the following C function to see how it would compile:

```
uint64_t lmul(uint32_t a, uint32_t b){
    uint32_t hia = a >> 16,
        hib = b >> 16,
        loa = (uint32_t)(uint16_t)a,
        lob = (uint32_t)(uint16_t)b,
        low = loa * lob,
        mid1 = hia * lob,
        mid2 = loa * hib,
        mid = mid1 + mid2,
        high = hia * hib;

    if (mid < mid1)
        high += 0x10000;
    return ((uint64_t)high << 32) + ((uint64_t)mid << 16) + low;
}
```

After compiling it with the ARM GCC compiler 4.7.3 through CodeWarrior (what came with the Freescale dev board I'm using) with size optimization, it turned into this:

```
00000eac <lmul>:
     eac:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
     eae:   0c06        lsrs    r6, r0, #16
     eb0:   b280        uxth    r0, r0
     eb2:   0c0a        lsrs    r2, r1, #16
     eb4:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
     eb6:   b289        uxth    r1, r1
     eb8:   434c        muls    r4, r1
     eba:   4350        muls    r0, r2
     ebc:   4371        muls    r1, r6
     ebe:   1843        adds    r3, r0, r1
     ec0:   4356        muls    r6, r2
     ec2:   428b        cmp r3, r1
     ec4:   d202        bcs.n   ecc <lmul+0x20>
     ec6:   2580        movs    r5, #128    ; 0x80
     ec8:   026a        lsls    r2, r5, #9
     eca:   18b6        adds    r6, r6, r2
     ecc:   0c19        lsrs    r1, r3, #16
     ece:   0418        lsls    r0, r3, #16
     ed0:   1c22        adds    r2, r4, #0
     ed2:   2300        movs    r3, #0
     ed4:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
     ed6:   1c0d        adds    r5, r1, #0
     ed8:   18a4        adds    r4, r4, r2
     eda:   415d        adcs    r5, r3
     edc:   1c31        adds    r1, r6, #0
     ede:   1c18        adds    r0, r3, #0
     ee0:   1c22        adds    r2, r4, #0
     ee2:   1c2b        adds    r3, r5, #0
     ee4:   1812        adds    r2, r2, r0
     ee6:   414b        adcs    r3, r1
     ee8:   1c10        adds    r0, r2, #0
     eea:   1c19        adds    r1, r3, #0
     eec:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

I cannot fathom what the compiler is doing in the last 40% of the function. It's like it's playing musical registers for no other purpose than to increase the size of the function. Is this something ARM is known to do, or is there some strange purpose to this that I lack the ARM assembly expertise to comprehend?

If I didn't make any mistakes in substitution the last half of the function could be represented by:

```
 ecc:   0c19        lsrs    r1, r3, #16
 ece:   0418        lsls    r0, r3, #16
 ed2:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 ed8:   18a4        adds    r0, r0, r4
 eda:   415d        adcs    r1, r3
 ee6:   414b        adds    r1, r1, r6
 eec:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

Comment: FYI, gcc 4.5.3 and 4.6.3 on [gcc explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) don't seem to do this.

Comment: LOL +1 just for 'musical registers'

Comment: One thing that was kind of a premise of my post but I'm not entirely sure of, is whether the compiler is actually from ARM or is just GCC which supports ARM. I was guessing the former because it's listed as "ARM Ltd. GCC Build Tools" in CodeWarrior, but I could be wrong. As I understand it the official ARM compiler uses the GCC front end but different backend.

Comment: There are various gcc options, such as `-dumpspecs` which give configuration info.  In the *gcc explorer*, there are about 30 instructions with 4.6.3 and `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -Os`.  The generated code seems horrible.  I would guess the casts and some obscure standards treatment of overflows.  Did you try `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this occurs in vanilla GCC 4.7.3 (i.e. not the version that came with CodeWarrior)?

Comment: I have (Linaro GCC 4.7-2012.10) 4.7.3 20121001, generated code looks the same as topic starter has.

Comment: Please try more recent compilers. With 4.9, the code seems fine (at least you don't get a gazillion "add*" at the end).

Comment: Thanks all for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the CodeWarrior tool chain, but I decided to try this with uVision using the ARMCC compiler v 5.03.0.76.  Optimizing for space is the default option (`-Ospace`) and the generated code was still pretty ugly... not too different from yours.  When I compiled with the `-O2` it looked more like what you would expect:

```
0x0000008A B570      PUSH     {r4-r6,lr}
0x0000008C 0C02      LSRS     r2,r0,#16
0x0000008E 0C0C      LSRS     r4,r1,#16
0x00000090 B280      UXTH     r0,r0
0x00000092 B289      UXTH     r1,r1
0x00000094 4606      MOV      r6,r0
0x00000096 4615      MOV      r5,r2
0x00000098 434D      MULS     r5,r1,r5
0x0000009A 4360      MULS     r0,r4,r0
0x0000009C 434E      MULS     r6,r1,r6
0x0000009E 182B      ADDS     r3,r5,r0
0x000000A0 4362      MULS     r2,r4,r2
0x000000A2 42AB      CMP      r3,r5
0x000000A4 D202      BCS      0x000000AC
0x000000A6 2001      MOVS     r0,#0x01
0x000000A8 0400      LSLS     r0,r0,#16
0x000000AA 1812      ADDS     r2,r2,r0
0x000000AC 2400      MOVS     r4,#0x00
0x000000AE 0C19      LSRS     r1,r3,#16
0x000000B0 0418      LSLS     r0,r3,#16
0x000000B2 1900      ADDS     r0,r0,r4
0x000000B4 4151      ADCS     r1,r1,r2
0x000000B6 1980      ADDS     r0,r0,r6
0x000000B8 4161      ADCS     r1,r1,r4
0x000000BA BD70      POP      {r4-r6,pc}
```

You can try compiling with different optimization options but I would suggest that you go with a newer compiler as Marc Glisse states in his comment.

Comment: So I guess the answer to the original question is "no": it appears to be a bug in both ARMCC and GCC.